# Spring security and LDAP ACL

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security, active-directory

I have currently made an application using Spring security and ACL (Access control list). I am currently in the process of learning about Active Directory and the LDAP protocol. I am going to create a second application and I want to store the user information in a central repository.

But I don't find any information about using ACL and LDAP/Active Directory. Is it possible/normal to store information about which Java object an user can read/modify in a LDAP repository or should this information stay in the database as it is today?